# Undercover gem not reporting missing coverage for new method in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to implement Undercover gem in a project.Now facing an issue with the Undercover gem in my Ruby on Rails project. I added a new method to my User class without writing tests for it, but when I run Undercover, it does not report any missing coverage for the newly added method.

Here are the details of my setup:

1. Ruby version: 2.7.2
2. Rails version: 6.1.4
3. Undercover gem version:0.4.7
4. Testing framework: RSpec

Project structure: Monolithic with separate frontend and backend directories

```
my_project/
|-- frontend/
|   |-- [frontend files and directories]
|-- backend/
|   |-- app/
|       |-- controllers/
|       |-- models/
|           |-- user.rb (contains the new method)   
|   |-- coverage
|-- [other directories and files]
```

I've already checked the following:

- I have run undercover command from my backend directory console like this `undercover -g ../.git`
  Because my `.git` file exist in root directory and my coverage file in backend folder/directory.
- For Implementing Undercover gem I followed this link: https://github.com/grodowski/undercover
- After adding a new method I have committed that change.

Am I doing the right things to test Undercover Gem is working or not. (if not, Can you Please write a way where I can see that Undercover Gem will report missing test)

Output Of SimpleCov Coverage
[Output Of SimpleCov Coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PM0G.png)

Comment: Undercover doesn't seem to add much on top of what Simplecov already offers. Why do you need it? Did you follow the full setup, did you install and configure simplecov-lcov, run tests, etc? Undercover works on results produced by simplecov, it doesn't measure coverage itself

Comment: @MikeSzyndel Yes I follow the full setup including Simplecov as well. Yes Undercover works on results produced by simplecov. First I run the test new lcov file was generated named backend.lcov, the i run undercover from terminal it shows  undercover: ✅ No coverage is missing in latest changes
Though I have added a new method without writing rspec of that.

Comment: Oh ok, but the new method isn't used anywhere, it's dead code? I'm not sure how is that treated

Comment: @MikeSzyndel Yes the method is a dead code. I have added it to check undercover working perfectly or not. Though after your comment i have modified a used method, add condition over there but result is same undercover: ✅ No coverage is missing in latest changes

Comment: Since data is generated by simplecov I would try to set output to default (html) and see what it shows you there. See github repo for an example of how it looks

Comment: @MikeSzyndel here it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PM0G.png

Comment: You can click on file name and see the details line by line

Comment: OK But I can see that for SimpleCov Gem not for Undercover right? So why it is showing undercover: ✅ No coverage is missing in latest changes even i know there are some missing test.

Comment: I don't know why I need to squeeze information out of you, but I'm tired of it. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's not possible to answer your question based on information provided.